# ERROR: Access is denied, when creating scheduled task

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Create task command: '/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/schtasks.exe /create /SC MINUTE /MO 10 /TN "Name of task" /TR "D:\path\to\exe /REQUIRED_PARAMETER" /RU System /F'
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

One of the tips I found was to run this:

```
cd\
cacls c:\windows\tasks /T /E /P Administrators:F
cacls c:\windows\tasks /T /E /P SYSTEM:F
```

A few other things:

- I confirmed that the Task Scheduler service is running
- The Event Viewer didn't show anything specific to the task creation
- I've captured and filtered events in `Procmon`, where no events with the results `ACCESS DENIED` could be found.
- The user is part of a group (ie Users) having `read` and `execute` on `schedtasks.exe`
- The user has full access to `c:\Windows\tasks` manually provided
- The user owns the folder of the executable targetted with the task

**Edit #1**

- User creating the task is not part of Administrators. When I put him into Administrators, it works. However, we believe that he shouldn't be in Administrators.